# Using other gcc version as provided with XCode in Snow leopard?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, macports

Makes it sense to use newer versions of gcc-compiler (4.5.3) from macports instead of standard compiler per default provided with xcode (4.2.1).

I'm don't develop any Mac related programs. I'm working with C++ in Eclipse. Would I benefit from newer gcc version or i would get a lot of compatibility problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **GCC** that comes with **XCode** was tweaked by Apple to their Operating System. Stick with the **default** if you don't need specific features from newer versions available on macports (which, by the way, were not build by Apple).

[Replacing xcode with macports software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587630/replacing-xcode-with-macports-software/4587854#4587854)

Also, check the interesting notes of **[UsingTheRightCompiler](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler)** before adventuring on that.